# how to update listview text when clicked the listview item

Tags: android

I  design an app which shows a list of wifi networks available and it shows the wifi connection setting dialog box when it is selected.if i  connect to wifi it will change the wifi state connected or not in listview textview.  Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            TextView your_text=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.your_text_id)
            your_text.setText("whatever you want")

        }
    });
```

or if you want to edit the text from the values sent to the adapter
you will need to clear update and call this

```
yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and next time post what you tried first

Comment: thanks but if i scroll the listview, changed  text is gone why?

Comment: Then use **customadapter** and **viewholder** in getview() function to solve the **"changed text is gone"** problem

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update adapter of that listview.After that call notifydatasetChanged(); .Its because on scroll listview will display original value if you not updated adapter.